# Dynamically creating date periods using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I trying to get the Grape count from dates March 1 - 3.

[image]

You will notice that on March 2 - there are no grapes inserted..

I'st possible to show a query from dates March 1, 2 and 3 but showing 0 count for March 2
[image]

In this image above only shows dates where there are grapes..

Here is mySQL query

```
SELECT  `fruitDate` ,  `fruitName` , COUNT( * ) 
FROM  `tbl_fruits` 
WHERE  `fruitName` =  "Grapes"
GROUP BY  `fruitDate
```

UPDATE 2:

Using this query:

```
SELECT f.fruitDate, f.fruitName, f1.count FROM tbl_fruits f
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT fruitDate, COUNT(*) as count from tbl_fruits d WHERE d.fruitName='Grapes' GROUP BY d.fruitDate) as f1 ON (f.fruitDate = f1.fruitDate) 
    GROUP BY f.fruitDate
```

I got this result..but its dsplaying diffrent fruit..something wrong with my query?

[image]

Comment: If there weren't any Apple, Orange nor Grape entries in day 2 (a gap)... how should the result look like?

Comment: it shows no fruit name on the result and null values for day 2

Comment: Setting Up a Time Dimension Table in MySQL: http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/setting-up-a-time-dimension-table-in-mysql/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember there is a dynamically (and a bit ugly) solution to creating a date range that does not require creating a table:

```
select aDate from (
  select @maxDate - interval (a.a+(10*b.a)+(100*c.a)+(1000*d.a)) day aDate from
  (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
   union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
   select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) a, /*10 day range*/
  (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
   union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
   select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) b, /*100 day range*/
  (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
   union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
   select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) c, /*1000 day range*/
  (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
   union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
   select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d, /*10000 day range*/
  (select @minDate := '2001-01-01', @maxDate := '2002-02-02') e
) f
where aDate between @minDate and @maxDate
```

Depending on the length of the date range you can reduce the amount of dynamically generated results (10000 days means over 27 years of records each representing one day) by removing tables (d, c, b and a) and removing them from the upper formula. Setting the `@minDate` and `@maxDate` variables will allow you to specify the dates between you want to filter the results.

**Edit:**

I see you're still looking for a solution. Try this:

```
select c.date, f.fruitName, count(f.fruitName = 'Grapes')
from tbl_calendar c
left join tbl_fruits f
on c.date = f.fruitDate and f.fruitName = 'Grapes'
group by c.date, f.fruitName
```

If you also want to filter the extra dates from the created table, use this query:

```
select c.date, f.fruitName, count(f.fruitName = 'Grapes')
from tbl_calendar c
left join tbl_fruits f
on c.date = f.fruitDate and f.fruitName = 'Grapes'
group by c.date, f.fruitName
having c.date between
  (select min(fruitDate) from tbl_fruits) and
  (select max(fruitDate) from tbl_fruits)
```

Comment: uh..this sores my eyes..lol..i knew this but i think this is too much code..LOL..thanks anyway/.i may also use this in the future..

Comment: I liked your 1st code..but it returns a null value if there a are no grapes in the query..can we show Grapes instead of null?

Answer (score 6):

March 2 is data that does not exist in your table, what would it select from?  That is to say, since `count()` is counting the number of rows that *exist* for "Grapes" on each date, and no rows exist for "Grapes" on March 2, `count()` has no data to count, nothing at all to tell the database to interpolate missing dates.

In order to solve this, what I have done in the past is create a separate table, Calendar, that contains a row for each date for a given range.  Then, you can `JOIN` to this table to assure you select a row for each date.  It might look something like this:

```
SELECT cal.`Date`, 'Grapes' as `fruitName`, COUNT(f.`fruitName`)
FROM `tbl_Calendar` cal 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_fruits` f ON cal.`Date` = f.`fruitDate`  
WHERE `fruitName` = "Grapes"
 AND '2012-03-01' <= cal.`Date` AND cal.`Date` <= '2012-03-03' 
GROUP BY cal.`Date`
```

Note that `count(*)` would never return 0 because a row would be returned for each date.  To get a 0, count a field that would be NULL when 0 rows are found, in this case, I count `fruitName`

The Calendar table could be as simple as

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Calendar (
  `Date` date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Which you would fill with a simple PHP loop from a chosen start date to end date.  You may find a benefit in adding other columns to cache things like day-of-week or holidays, but that is not needed for this task.

**EDIT**

In your edit, you seem to be trying to join back to your fruits table to get dates, but you have some errors in your query, try instead to substitute a similar subquery in place of my Calendar table:

```
SELECT cal.`Date`, 'Grapes' as `fruitName`, COUNT(f.`fruitName`)
FROM (SELECT `fruitDate` as `Date` FROM `tbl_fruits` GROUP BY `fruitDate`) cal 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_fruits` f ON cal.`Date` = f.`fruitDate`  
WHERE `fruitName` = "Grapes"
GROUP BY cal.`Date`
```

Note, though, while this will fill in dates missing for Grapes that are not missing for some other fruits, it will not fill in dates which are missing for all fruits.

Comment: can you tell me the table name and fields you made on this example? I wanna replicate this to use this code..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, perhaps the trivial CREATE will help?

Comment: THanks for you help umbrella..I was a bit confused on what you said that "March 2 is data that does not exist in your table," I have my tbl_fruits table on the 1st screentshot on my question. The result from my query is the 2nd screenshot which shows March 1 and 3 only. My query is the 3rd screenshot..:)

Comment: I guess this comes down to opinion, but I feel it would be a better solution in terms of keeping the schema clean to insert the missing days in application code rather than at the data layer.

Comment: I appreciate all you kind help. I tried this query: SELECT f.fruitDate, f.fruitName, f1.count FROM tbl_fruits f
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT fruitDate, COUNT(*) as count from tbl_fruits d WHERE d.fruitName='Grapes' GROUP BY d.fruitDate) as f1 ON (f.fruitDate = f1.fruitDate) 
    GROUP BY f.fruitDate..but i get a different fruit name..anything wrong with my query? see screenshot for upddates

Comment: I have also used that approach.  It is a trade off, with the former keeping the application code clean, since the data layer returns the complete/desired data.

Comment: But it seems like my fruit name has gone crazy..it shows apples and oranges instead of grapes..LOL

Comment: Yes, your query has errors.  For one, your placement of the "Grapes" test.  See my edit for an other approach, and a related warning.

Comment: Using this query " SELECT f.fruitDate, f.fruitName, f1.count FROM tbl_fruits f
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT fruitDate, COUNT(*) as count from tbl_fruits d WHERE d.fruitName='Grapes' GROUP BY d.fruitDate) as f1 ON (f.fruitDate = f1.fruitDate) 
    GROUP BY f.fruitDate " can i assign 0, instead of null? where do I insert IFNULL on this query?

Comment: @SalmanA Are you referring to one of mine?  Sure.  It's late here, and I haven't tested these.